# I want to make graph trend line combined with barplot. it seems an error

Tags: python, data-science, e-commerce

[dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/olistbr/brazilian-ecommerce)

I want to make graph trend line combined with barplot. it seems an error

```
order_date = ['order_purchase_timestamp']
new_data[order_date] = new_data[order_date].apply(pd.to_datetime)
new_data['order_year'] = new_data['order_purchase_timestamp'].dt.year
new_data['order_month'] = new_data['order_purchase_timestamp'].dt.month
monthly_purchase = new_data.groupby(['order_year', 'order_month'])['payment_value'].sum()

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
width = .35 # width of a bar

monthly_purchase.plot(kind='bar', width = width, color='blue')
monthly_purchase['payment_value'].plot(secondary_y=True)

ax = plt.gca()

plt.title('Total Purchase Amount per Month')
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Total Purchase Amount')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
ax.set_xticklabels(('order_month'))
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

It seems error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: 'payment_value'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/md/yk6b90ws0hnf12rp68hmchy00000gn/T/ipykernel_21229/881730175.py in <module>
      4 
      5 monthly_purchase.plot(kind='bar', width = width, color='blue')
----> 6 monthly_purchase['payment_value'].plot(secondary_y=True)
      7 
      8 ax = plt.gca()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    956 
    957         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 958             return self._get_value(key)
    959 
    960         if is_hashable(key):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1067 
   1068         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1069         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1070         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
   1071 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2867 
   2868         if not isinstance(key, tuple):
-> 2869             loc = self._get_level_indexer(key, level=0)
   2870             return _maybe_to_slice(loc)
   2871 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in _get_level_indexer(self, key, level, indexer)
   3220         else:
   3221 
-> 3222             idx = self._get_loc_single_level_index(level_index, key)
   3223 
   3224             if level > 0 or self._lexsort_depth == 0:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py in _get_loc_single_level_index(self, level_index, key)
   2800             return -1
   2801         else:
-> 2802             return level_index.get_loc(key)
   2803 
   2804     def get_loc(self, key, method=None):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:
-> 3631                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'payment_value'
```